# Pick line in csv file to pull data

Tags: python, csv

I have a code that is working for me in a Cinema 4d project.  It is able to read 4 different data points and kick out outputs to the main project.  Currently it is reading all of the lines of the csv file and I would like to pick one line and pull the data from that line only.

```
import c4d
import csv


def main():

    path = Spreadsheet #Spreadsheet is an input filename path

    with open(path, 'rb') as csv_file:
        readed = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')

        for i, row in enumerate(readed):
            try:
                Xcord = float(row["hc_x"])
                Ycord = float(row["hc_y"])
                Langle = float(row["launch_angle"])
                Lspeed = float(row["launch_speed"])

            except:
                print "Error while reading - {}".format(row)
                continue


    global Output1
    global Output2
    global Output3
    global Output4

    Output1 = Xcord
    Output2 = Ycord
    Output3 = Langle
    Output4 = Lspeed
```

This is about the first thing I have tried to code. So thanks.

Comment: what is the line you are looking for? it is not clear.

Comment: Best to avoid "bare" `except:` clauses because they can hide unexpected problem (like `SyntaxError`s for example). Regardless, you can terminate the `for` loop with a `break` when it's time to do so.

Comment: @balderman I was going to make the line a variable, but  lets just call it 5

Comment: @ShaneEnglish So are you interested in line number 5? Or in line that contains 5? Share few lines of the file and explain how to identify the requested line.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid loading the whole contents into memory and use the csv file a bit like a database that you get a specified line from?

Comment: @balderman Line 5.  The data is usually in a much larger file.hc_x hc_y launch_speed launch_angle
41.94 79.01 99.3 23
39.86 58.16 101.6 33
37.06 40.09 114.2 34
17.73 63.55 105.8 27
14.63 54.32 111.7 31
20.32 88.19 104.9 26
24.17 61.47 108.9 31
64.44 44.15 108.5 24
189.94 54.06 102.5 30

Comment: @ShaneEnglish - see my answer - it will return to you the line by index.

Comment: Since your are using `enumerate`, you can stop after reading line #5 with `if i == 4: break`. The reason it's `4` and not `5` is because counting starts with line `0`.

Comment: @martineau Thank you.  I was able to add this and it worked like a charm

Comment: Shane: Good to hear. Note you can use `for i, row in enumerate(readed, start=1):` and `break` when it's line `5` if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

[csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) requires that you open the file with newline="" in order for it to parse the file correctly.

```
with open(path, 'rb', newline="") as csv_file:
        readed = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
```

You also don't have any condition to stop reading the file.

```
        row_to_stop = 5
        for i, row in enumerate(readed):
            if i == row_to_stop:
                Xcord = float(row["hc_x"])
                Ycord = float(row["hc_y"])
                Langle = float(row["launch_angle"])
                Lspeed = float(row["launch_speed"])
                break
```

If you only care about one line, don't look up and type cast values until you reach the line you care about.

Comment: FYI, the `newline=""` is really only important if the rows of the CSV file have field that contain newlines (and most don't). Also note that enumerate counts from `0` by default, not `1` and your code assumes.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to pick one line and pull the data from that line only

The code below will return specific line (by index). You will have to split it and grab the data.

```
def get_interesting_line(file_name: str, idx: int):
    cnt = 0
    with open(file_name) as f:
        while cnt != idx:
            f.readline()
            cnt += 1
        return f.readline().strip()

# usage example below
print(get_interesting_line('data.txt',7))
```